# Angular 6.0.5 - Cannot access property that's there

Tags: javascript, angular

I, for the life of me cannot understand why I can't access a property on an angular 6 class.  Here is some code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-badge-component',
  templateUrl: './badge.component.html'
})

export class AdminBadgeComponent implements OnInit {

    // Badge Object
    public badgeObject: IVisitorBadge = null;

    // On Init
    public ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {

      // Get Badge Object From API    
      this.visitorService.getVisitorBadge(params['aid'],params['vid'])
        .subscribe((response: IVisitorBadge) => {

          console.log(response);
          this.badgeObject = response;
        });
      });
    }
}
```

the `console.log` outputs every thing as intended:

```
{
  "id":2,
  "visit_id":325,
  "visitor_id":45,
  "created_at":"2018-09-29 15:00:10",
  "updated_at":"2018-09-29 15:00:10",
  "visitor": {
    ...
    "firstname": "matthew",
    "lastname": "brown",
    ...
  }
}
```

However, when I goto access and display the visitor firstname in my template using the following code:

```
<div>
  <h3>
    {{ badgeObject?.visitor?.firstname }} {{ badgeObject?.visitor?.lastname }}
  </h3>
</div>
```

Nothing displays.  If I try to access the properties directly without the `?` notation, I get `cannot access 'firstname' of undefined`.  Even if I wrap the template in `*ngIf` and check for property first.  I've also tried initting and setting a `loadingBool` that gets set to false after I have the API response, and using it in the `*ngIf` still nothing.

Here is screenshot of full class: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBGFa.jpg

Comment: So if i understand well  badgeObject is defined but  badgetObject.visitor is undefined ?

Comment: @xrobert35 that's correct. After setting `this.badgeObject = response`  I can console.log out `this.badgeObject` and it displays the json structure in my question.  It's only when I access this.badgeObject.visitor.firstname does it act like badgeObject.visitor undefined.

Comment: If you bind  badgeObject.id  you see "2" ?

Comment: Interesting, no I also get `undefined` error. Which is weird because I am binding it, I can even see in Chrome network tools the JSON is valid and as expected.  Not shown above, elsewhere in the code I bind other properties from different API calls that work just fine.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, this is the actual screenshot of the full class: https://imgur.com/a/eEfCSL3

Comment: I have an assumption! :D can you remove the outer route-params subscription, and just hardcode an API call `onInit` and tell me if it works? maybe extra observables fireup with invalid data after the first one?

Answer (score 1):

```
  public constructor(private _change: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  this.visitorService.getVisitorBadge(params['aid'],params['vid'])
    .subscribe((response: IVisitorBadge) => {
      this.badgeObject = response;
      this._change.markForCheck();
    });
  });
```

You have to tell the change detector that the component is dirty when you lazy load data. The first time the template is rendered the value of `badgeObject` is `null`, but later it is assigned a value.

Use the ChangeDetectorRef:

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: Thanks for this, I did find the answer - it was unrelated but this is useful information to have!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Not mentioned above is the `this.visitorService.getVisitorBadge` method, which I was accidentally setting the responseType to `text` in the HttpClient callout.  Reset that back to `json`, now it's working.